# NavigationLink seems to take only a fiew space

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working with NavigatonView and NavigationLink, I've made my view like that :

```
ScrollView{
    VStack{
        // MARK: - Survey and tips Navigation
        HStack(spacing:9){
            NavigationLink(destination:Container.sharedContainer.resolve(SurveyListView.self,argument: $VM.occurrences)!){
                iconHome(image: "img-survey", icon: "icon-survey", text: "surveys_upper_case")}
            NavigationLink(destination:Container.sharedContainer.resolve(SurveyListView.self,argument: $VM.occurrences)!){
                iconHome(image: "img-tip", icon: "icon-tip", text: "tips_upper_case")}

        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .padding(.horizontal,37)
    .background(Color.red)
}
```

iconHome is another struct which implements view protocol :

```
struct iconHome : View{

    var image:String
    var icon:String
    var text:LocalizedStringKey
    var body : some View{
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                ZStack{
                    Image(self.image)
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width ,height:geometry.size.width)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                    VStack{
                        Image(self.icon)
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 5,height:geometry.size.width / 5 )
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        Text(self.text)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .modifier(OpenSansBoldModifier(fontSize: 12))
                    }
                }
                .shadow(radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
        }
    }
}
```

I've got a strange result :
[image: my result]

I don't why but my HStack which contains my two navigation link have only red rectangle high ... so it's hard to click on him ... any idea about why the HStack doesn't have the good high ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is missing a Fill mode for the `geometry`

```
  GeometryReader{ geometry in
   ....
   }.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
```